# Название трека с помощью AVAudioplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть массив треков, находящихся в памяти программы. Как с помощью класса AVAudioplayer определить индекс или название воспроизведенного в данный момент трека?

```
songsArrau = @[@"Rain.mp3", @"Daze.mp3", @"Temple of Thought.mp3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что у Вас где-то в коде подобным образом создаётся проигрыватель звуковых дорожек:

```
NSError* error;
AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:songsArrau[0]] error:&error];
```

В таком случае во время воспроизведения звуковой дорожки можно узнать полное имя файла с помощью данного обращения к свойствам переменной `player`:

```
NSString* fileNameWithPath = player.url.absoluteString;
```

Имя файла без пути к нему можно узнать так:

```
NSString* fileName = fileNameWithPath.lastPathComponent;
```